# C# Loop through array using array.length and adding prices from MSSQL server. Based on array index

Tags: c#, sql-server

Okay so this is a little head scratcher for you guys :-)

What i am trying to do is to:

1. Collect data from MSSQL server
2. Collect inputs in variables(Done and not included)
3. Loop through array based upon the array.length
4. check if the position in the array 'array' is true
5. Execute the code in the if statement
6. Add the price of the 'Values' list based on the array index

   ```
    int Samletpris = 695;
       List<int> values = new List<int>();

       string SQL = "SELECT Pris FROM Vare;";        //SQL Command to execute
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, vars.connection))
       {
           using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       values.Add(reader.GetInt16(0));

                   }
               }
           }

           foreach (int price in values)
           {
               System.Console.WriteLine(price);
           }


           string[] array = new string[] {Suite, EnkeltSeng, ToSenge, DobbeltSeng, Altan, Spa, Badekar};
       for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
       {

           if (array[i] == 1)
               int SamletPris + values[i];
       }
   ```

From my experience, everything down to the if statement is correct, as it's just data. Is what i'm trying to do even possible?

(Also i know that my code is a little messy, i will clean it when i find a solution)

Comment: what did you expect to happen vs what actually happened?

Comment: @John I know, not the issue. Forgot to edit it in

Comment: @John I know what to do to get it to work, i edited the snippet.

Comment: Because it's the if statement that i can't get to work, not because i don't know how to format it, but because i can't get it to pull the value from Value based on the index. Look at the snippet again :-)

Comment: I dont understand your logic but "if (array[i] == 1)   int SamletPris + values[i];" This statment must be like "if (array[i] == "Suite")   SamletPris += values[i];"

Comment: @EsatARSLAN What i am doing is trying to check if a string or bool (I haven't decided) is either true/fale or 1 or 0 in an array. Then add the values from the list to the variable, based on the index number of the array

Comment: I don't understand how `array` relates to `values`? Is `array` effectively a mask of `values`? (i.e. if position 1 in array is true, take value 1, if position 6 is true, take value 6)?

Comment: @John, there isn't really any relation, i just want to use the index number from array to take the data in the values list, and add it to the variable SamletPris

Comment: @John The array is populated in the same sequence as the list, so the index 0 of array matches the index 0 of values.

Comment: So it _is_ effectively a mask? OK, now I understand that. What is the problem with what you're already doing?

Comment: @John I found a solution

Comment: Then you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @John I just did :-)

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled around and found a solution myself. I have included the rest of the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;


namespace SQL
{
    class TimTest
    {
        public TimTest()
        {
            vars vars = new vars();     // Import vars
            vars.connection.Open();     // Open SQL Connection




            string streg = "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";

            Console.WriteLine(streg);


            //Fornavn(e)
            Console.WriteLine(" Indtast gæstens fornavn(e)");
            string Fornavn = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Efternavn
            Console.WriteLine(" Indtast gæstens efternavn");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Efternavn = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Adresse
            Console.WriteLine(" Indtast gæstens adresse (Vej og husnummer og Sal/Dør hvis nødvendigt)");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Adresse = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Postnummer
            Console.WriteLine(" Indtast gæstens postnummer (Vi behøver ikke bynavn) ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            int PostNr = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
            Console.Clear();

            //Telefonnummer
            Console.WriteLine(" Indtast gæstens telefon nummer (Dette må gerne være tomt) ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            int TlfNummer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
            Console.Clear();

            //Email
            Console.WriteLine(" Indtast gæstens email adresse (Dette felt må gerne være tomt)");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Email = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();


            //Suite
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten opgraderes til en suite? ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Suite = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Enmands seng
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have et enkelt seng på værelset? Skriv JA | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string EnkeltSeng = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();


            //2x enmands seng
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have 2 enkelt senge på værelset? Skriv Ja | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string ToSenge = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Dobbeltseng
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have en dobbelt seng på værelset? Skriv Ja | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string DobbeltSeng = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Altan
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have en altan tilknyttet sit værelse? Skriv Ja | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Altan = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Køkken
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have eget køkken? Skriv Ja | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Køkken = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Badekar
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have badekar på værelset? Skriv Ja | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Badekar = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Jacuzzi 
            Console.WriteLine(" Vil gæsten have spabad på værelset? skriv Ja | Nej ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            string Jacuzzi = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            Console.Clear();

            //Opholdets start
            Console.WriteLine(" Hvad dato vil gæsten starte sit ophold? ");
            Console.WriteLine(streg);
            DateTime StartDato = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine()); 




            List<int> values = new List<int>();

            string SQL = "SELECT Pris FROM Vare;";        //SQL Command to execute
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, vars.connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                            values.Add( reader.GetInt16(0));
                    }
                }

                int prisTotal = 695;

                string[] array = new string[] { "GrundPrisPlaceholder", Suite, EnkeltSeng, ToSenge, DobbeltSeng, Altan, Køkken, Badekar, Jacuzzi };
                for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i] == "JA")
                        prisTotal += values[i];
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n Den totale pris er: " + prisTotal);

                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
            vars.connection.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Sorry I couldn't quite understand the issue you were experiencing.

Comment: @John it's cool man, i got a lot on my plate atm, so i came off as an asshat, sorry :D